# How can I configure fields in a custom lightning record form as an admin?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am very new to Salesforce and am currently trying to create a custom LWC for a project that has specific capabilities.

I have created a custom LWC, which is a lightning-record-form to be able to view and edit specific user information/fields. The form works fine in Salesforce, in the sense that I can view and edit all of the fields that I have included.

My next dilemma is that one of the requirements, requires the System Admin to be able to configure which fields are available AND editable for logged in users.

At this stage I'm not quite sure if I have used the right base component (lightning-record-form) for these requirements. I'm also not sure if I am knowledgeable enough yet with the Salesforce platform to know how to configure these fields as an Admin, or if this is even do-able to start with.

Another requirement is to make this form optimized for both Desktop AND Mobile. I understand the lightning-record-form is already optimized for mobile, but is there any way to override the styling if needed? (I haven't played with styling in LWC as of yet).

I have included my code below for reference:

userProfileForm.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import USER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/User';
import FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.FirstName';
import LASTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.LastName'
import ALIAS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Alias';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email';
import USERNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Username';
import NICKNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.CommunityNickname';
import TITLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Title';
import COMPANY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.CompanyName';
import DEPARTMENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Department';
import ADDRESS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Address';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Phone';
import MOBILE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.MobilePhone';
import TIMEZONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.TimeZoneSidKey';
import LOCALE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.LocaleSidKey';
import LANGUAGE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.LanguageLocaleKey';

export default class UserProfileForm extends LightningElement {
    modeName = 'view'; // Sets mode to view in lightning-record-form
    objectApiName = USER_OBJECT;
    userId = Id; // Gets current user id from salesforce

    // Exposes fields to be made available in the form template
    fields = [
        FIRSTNAME_FIELD,
        LASTNAME_FIELD, 
        ALIAS_FIELD, 
        EMAIL_FIELD, 
        USERNAME_FIELD, 
        NICKNAME_FIELD, 
        TITLE_FIELD, 
        COMPANY_FIELD, 
        DEPARTMENT_FIELD, 
        ADDRESS_FIELD, 
        PHONE_FIELD, 
        MOBILE_FIELD,
        TIMEZONE_FIELD, 
        LOCALE_FIELD, 
        LANGUAGE_FIELD
    ];

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stops form from submitting
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-form').submit(fields);
    }
    
    handleSuccess() {
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Updated Successfully",
            message: "User information has successfully been updated",
            variant: "success"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
    }

    handleError() {
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Update Unsuccessful",
            message: "Something went wrong, please try again",
            variant: "error"
        })
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
    }
}
```

userProfileForm.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="User Information" icon-name="action:user">
        <lightning-record-form
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            record-id={userId}
            fields={fields}
            mode={modeName}
            onsubmit={handleSubmit}
            onsuccess={handleSuccess}
            onerror={handleError}>
        </lightning-record-form>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very nice question and half the battle is knowing what to Google for...

Many ways to solve it, depending on what you actually need. A purist would tell you could look into fieldsets but they aren't very "native" for LWC yet, you'd need some helper Apex code to pull their definitions. Which is a shame because we can do pretty neat things with fieldsets in Visualforce.

Before you deep dive into coding it's sometimes worth poking the requirement a bit more. `User` object is probably bad choice for this because you don't get to control a lot with Profile/Permission Sets. But any other object - sometimes the right answer is to not do it, not make code changes. Make admin show/hide fields properly, in the profile. That way they'll be hidden everywhere, in normal layouts, listviews, reports, not just custom pieces.

Anyway.

Probably easiest for your admins is if you expose some parameters they could pass to your component. They could be passed from another component that's calling it but also from the App Builder (the drag&drop page editor), they'd drop your component and then configure it in right side menu.

**If you have time**

- Read up about `@api` [decorator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators)
- And how to [expose parameters so sysadmin can decide on some behaviour while dropping it on the page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_app_builder). How to clearly label them, define ranges like "max 3 columns in the form, otherwise it'll look messy"
- explore the "lwc-recipes" github repo, for example https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/recordFormDynamicContact (link to it is at the bottom of [lightning-record-form spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation))
- There's very cool LWC crash course at https://developerforce.github.io/LWC-Developer-Workshop-2019/index.html. **I can't recommend it enough** (although it'd be better with the actual teacher who can show you stuff, I was lucky to join a 1-day classroom for it in 2019). Try to do the whole thing. In exercise 6 you do pretty cool things with record-form, get more comfortable with the config options. Then in exercise 7 you rip the whole thing apart and make **completely dynamic generic form**. (Almost) any object, any fields, any amount of columns, layout density... (in extreme cases your sysadmin could configure 2 components on same page, 1 displayed for desktop, 1 for mobile using [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5), search for "form factor")

**If you don't have time**

Jump straight to [exercise 7](https://developerforce.github.io/LWC-Developer-Workshop-2019/Exercise_7.html) and there's ready component at the bottom.

Just notice that this way of doing this (field names as strings, not as `@salesforce/schema/...`) doesn't come with protection against deleting and renaming. For standard fields on User you're safe, they're unlikely to go away. But for custom objects sometimes a compile time check/deployment error/error when somebody tries to delete the field is a nasty surprise but better than component not running for end users because you forgot to change it...

Comment: Thank you so much for all of this amazing information! You are a champion.
I guess I'm still slightly confused with my project overview. It's requiring me to create a custom LWC that has 15 specific fields from the User object, but not entirely sure how to then add that LWC to the digital experience for an admin to then check/uncheck fields to their liking, depending on what they want to show. Another requirement is for the admin to make the form editable only to their requirement, depending on the user.

Comment: Where you need it, lightning experience or community or what? Dropped to what page, user's home? Some record page? As a just dropped component or a button? "User" table is bit special, you don't work with checkboxes for each field but groups of permissions like "Manage users"... You might end up with component that works great for sysadmins but so-so for mortals